# Insert PHP Array Into Two Columns

Tags: php, arrays

I know it is possible to split an array to be inserted to multiple columns/rows but I just stumped.

Say we have something like this....
Array
(
    [john] => blue
    [lee] => red
    [sylva] => green
    [paul] => black
)

In my table, I have three columns namely id,name,color. How can I insert these elements so that the rows in my table are incremented (based on this array, it should be 4 rows altogether)..
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far (show more code)? What are you trying to do? What is "table"? A database table or html table?

Comment: What table do you mean? A database table or html table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to insert the arrays into database tables, then:

```
foreach($yourArr as $name => $color) {
  //your insert query here
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
  $color = mysql_real_escape_string($color);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ('$name', '$color')";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Do you mean something like this..

Comment: +1 for being the only answer utilizing proper string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter=1;  
foreach ($yourarray as $key=>$item){  
  ?> <tr>  
    <td> <? echo $counter; ?></td>  
    <td> <? echo $key; ?></td>  
    <td> <? echo $item; ?></td>

    </tr><?  
    $counter++;
}
```

If you mean html table.

Comment: Hi Ivil, thanks for your time...Actually it is a table in my MySQL database that stores students marks (indicated by colours). So, based on that array, the table should have 4 records (4 ids,4 names, 4 colours) - stored incrementedly inside the table...Simply said, in the end we should have 4 rows/records.

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` has auto_increment this is the solution I use:

```
$data = Array ( 'john' => 'blue', 'lee' => 'red', 'sylva' => 'green', 'paul' => 'black');
$items = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val) $items[]="('$key', '$val')";
$sql = "insert into table (`name`,`color`) values".implode(',',$items);
echo $sql;
```

Comment: that makes sense..but I'm having a MySQL problem that says Column count doesn't match value count at row 1... It reflects the two columns that I'm using to insert records.. :( Any idea?

Comment: foreach($data as $key => $val) $items[] = "('$key' , '$val')";

Comment: in the every string you put into query you have to escape some special characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = '';
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   $query .= "insert into table(name,color) values('".$key."','".$value."')";
}
echo $query;
```

as no of entries in array , your insert query will be build which you can fire to DB to update the table(assuming auto increment id)

Answer (score -1):

The better/optimal solution!

```
<?php

$data = Array ( 'john' => 'blue', 'lee' => 'red', 'sylva' => 'green', 'paul' => 'black');

$sqlPart='';
foreach($data as $key => $val)
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    $sqlPart .= "('$key' , '$val'), ";
$sqlPart = rtrim($sqlPart , ', ').';';
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table`(`name`,`color`) VALUES '.$sqlPart;
echo $sql;

?>
```

Outputs:

INSERT INTO `table` (`name`,`color`) VALUES

('john' , 'blue'), 
 ('lee' , 'red'), 
 ('sylva' , 'green'), 
 ('paul' , 'black');

Comment: This "optimal" solution lacks required SQL formatting. Added it for you this time but you have to be more accurate in the future. Also made readable statement out of your slashes-n-apostrophes craze.

Comment: ' works faster and mysql_real_escape_string is not only the requirement there are other functions too, to be used with it in terms of sql or script injections. Basic idea was to use array and I did perfectly well!

Comment: Oh, please, don't repeat that nonsense 'bout "work faster" after someone who have no clue. and also please note that mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with injections. it is a string formatting function and it is the only requirement here, you need nothing else. Nobody is talking of injections here - you are probably taking this function wrong. Basic idea is to give a proper answer that can be used without any danger, isn't it?

Comment: may be you are comfotable with "" but I am not and mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with it

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string indeed has nothing to do with PHP quotes. it is used to escape special characters in SQL strings.

Comment: Yes you are right, but my point is, in this array problem mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do

Comment: well, in fact, you didn't use any arrays beside one with initial data. it was someone else who actually used an array ;)

Comment: Urmm...now I have a question....what if I want to have 3 columns involved instead of two? I had some changes to be done that requires me to go to three columns.. =_=   ...I haven't found any clues to do this..Help.

Comment: Yes you actually have restricted it with key value pair! so I'll suggest to have multiple dimensional array! $data[0]['name'] = 'waqar'; $data[0]['color'] = 'white'; $data[0]['rank'] =1;